# Are groups with every proper, non-trivial subgroup infinite cyclic simple?

Tags: gr.group-theory

In the 1970s Ol'shanskii constructed a non-cyclic finitely generated group $G$ with the following properties:

1. Every proper, non-trivial subgroup of $G$ is infinite cyclic.
2. If $X^m=Y^n$ for $X, Y\in G$ with $m,n\neq0$, then $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is cyclic i.e., any two maximal subgroups of $G$ have trivial intersection.

Ol'shanskii gave an easy proof that such a group is simple, which roughly goes: Suppose $N$ is a proper, non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$. If $N$ is maximal then $G/N$ is cyclic of prime order, so $G$ is virtually-$N$, so $G$ is a torsion-free virtually-$\mathbb{Z}$ group, so must itself be cyclic. If $N$ is not maximal then $N$ is contained in a maximal subgroup $M$ such that $M^g\cap M\neq1$ for all $g\in G$, so as $M^g$ is also maximal and as maximal subgroups intersect trivially (by (2)) we have that $M^g=M$ for all $g\in G$, i.e. $M$ is normal in $G$, which is impossible by the previous case.

Property (2) was used here. I was wondering if this can be dropped. So:

**Question.** Suppose $G$ is a non-cyclic finitely generated group with every proper, non-trivial subgroup of $G$ infinite cyclic. Is $G$ simple?

---

If $G$ instead satisfies that it is infinite and every proper, non-trivial subgroup has order $p$ for a fixed prime $p$ then $G$ is a "Tarski monster" group and is indeed simple: If $N$ is a proper, non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ and $g\not\in N$ then $N\cap\langle g\rangle=1$, as both subgroups have prime order, so $N\langle g\rangle=N\rtimes\langle g\rangle$ has order $p^2$, a contradiction. However, this proof uses primality so does not extend to the setting here.

Comment: What about an infinite cyclic group?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle I meant to exclude that possibility! I'll edit the question to rule it out.

Comment: Small observation: Any normal subgroup is necessarily central. Assume $\langle x \rangle$ is normal, and there is $y$ with $yxy^{-1} = x^{-1}$. Then $\langle x,y\rangle$ cannot be cyclic, so it must be all of $G$. The subgroup $\langle x,y^2\rangle$ is abelian, thus a proper subgroup, and must be cyclic. So $G$ is a normal extension $\mathbb{Z}\to G \to C_2$ with sign action on $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus isomorphic to the infinite dihedral group, which contains $2$-torsion, contradiction.

Comment: Also note that if we do have nontrivial center $\langle x \rangle$, then $G/\langle x \rangle$ is a pretty weird group: It has the property that every proper subgroup is finite cyclic. It feels like one should be able to finish from here, but I haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: @AchimKrause Yes, I was getting tangled up with groups of this form too. I tried to mimic the proof that if $G$ is torsion-free and $G/\langle x\rangle$ is finite then $G$ is cyclic, and the idea here is to prove that $G$ splits. So for example if $H^2(G/\langle x\rangle, \mathbb{Z})=0$ then we'd be done, but I cannot see why this would be $0$.

Comment: I believe one also might try to indeed construct such examples of central extensions of Tarski monsters.

Comment: @ADL I think we can rule out the case of $G/\langle x\rangle$ finite: As discussed above, it must be a simple group (since the center $\langle x\rangle$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $G$), and every proper subgroup is cyclic. It cannot itself be cyclic, as then $G$ would be abelian. If $y\in G/\langle x\rangle$ has order $2$, it is either central or we find a nontrivial conjugate $y'$, and then $y, y'$ generate a dihedral subgroup. So $G/\langle x\rangle$ is either dihedral or odd, in both cases it cannot be simple.

Comment: @YCor: Cool, I wasn't aware of Tarski monsters. So there are plenty of groups that could occur as $G/\langle x \rangle$. I suppose we are precisely looking for a Tarski monster $H$ and a cohomology class in $H^2(H;\mathbb{Z})$ whose image in $H^2(C_p;\mathbb{Z})$ is nontrivial for all subgroups $C_p$.

Comment: @AchimKrause I was meaning trying to adapt the general proof of the case when $G/\langle x\rangle$ is finite to when $G/\langle x\rangle$ is torsion. It is a standard fact that if $G$ is torsion-free, $\langle x\rangle$ infinite cyclic and $G/\langle x\rangle$ is finite and then $G$ must be infinite cyclic - so can the proof be adapted?

Comment: @AchimKrause: If $G/Z(G)$ is finite, then the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is finite, by a theorem of Schur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no, there exist non-simple torsion-free Tarski monsters. Theorem 31.4 of Ol’shanskii's book "Geometry of defining relations in groups" [ZBL0676.20014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0676.20014) [MR1191619](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1191619) is:

**Theorem.** There is a non-abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are infinite cyclic and the intersection of any two of them is non-trivial.

Such a group necessarily has infinite cyclic centre: take any non-commuting $x$ and $y$, then the centralizer of $\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$ contains $\langle x, y \rangle$, which is the whole group. Thanks to Ashot Minasyan for pointing out Ol’shanskii's theorem.